# Resolving Exchange 2019 Management Shell startup failures

Tags: powershell, exchange, windows-server-2016, windows-server-2019

I am trying to figure out while Exchange Management Shell is continuing to fail.

I have made sure kerberos is enable on the IIS. I am not sure what else I can do to try to fix this issue.

> VERBOSE: Connecting to ExchangeServer.Website.com. New-PSSession :
>   [ExchangeServer.Website.com] Processing data from remote server
>   ExchangeServer.Website.com failed with the following error
>   message: The EndpointConfiguration with the
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/Microsoft.Exchange identifier
>   is not in a valid initial session state on the remote computer.
>   Contact your Windows PowerShell administrator, or the owner or creator
>   of the endpoint configuration. For more information, see the
>   about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic. At line:1 char:1
>   + New-PSSession -ConnectionURI "$connectionUri" -ConfigurationName Micr ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession],
>   PSRemotin    gTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : IncorrectProtocolVersion,PSSessionOpenFailed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you do before the error occurs? Have you changed certificate on IIS?

1.According to the error message above, it's suggested that checking the Exchange Servers Group at the following location on all Domain Controller.

Group Policy Management Editor under Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\User Rights AssignmentLocal Policies--> User Rights Assignments -->Manage auditing and security log--> “Exchange servers” group

If the Exchange Servers Group is missing, I suggest you try to update the GPO and test.

2. Create another administrator account and test, this is in order to check if this issue could be related to the AD account permission.

3.Navigate to IIS Manager--> Default Website--> PowerShell

Change the physical path from C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\FrontEnd\HttpProxy\PowerShell

to: C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Exchange Server\V15\ClientAccess\PowerShell

Then run IISRESET in CMD.

What's more, here’s a similar thread for your reference:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/713b7fa3-23ea-40d5-8187-a66ab8a0af90/exchange-server-control-not-transfering-successfully-on-remote-server?forum=exchangesvravailabilityandisasterrecovery

Comment: Is it called Microsoft Exchange Security Groups

Comment: Under DNS it had wrong codes that I updated.

Comment: Thank you so much for this!  It saved my butt.  Heads up for anyone else, IISRESET might give you an error that "you need administrator" while in an admin CMD.  You'll just need to run it again after a minute in the same CMD session.  It's mostly a problem with services not stopping in due time and windows tosses a generic error.

Answer (score 1):

Just had this same error when trying to launch Exchange 2016 Exchange Management Shell after some monthly patching and server reboots.

Trying to access Exchange Control Panel (ECP) in a browser was also giving a HTTP Error 503 "unable to handle this request"

The following Event ID 15021 was found in the System logs:

"An error occurred while using SSL configuration for endpoint 0.0.0.0:444.  The error status code is contained within the returned data."

The solution was to rebind a valid certificate to the "Exchange Back End" site in IIS on each Exchange server followed by an IISRESET.

These pages show the same steps in more detail:

https://martinsblog.dk/exchange-an-error-occurred-while-using-ssl-configuration-for-endpoint-0-0-0-0444/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/you-get-a-blank-page-after-logging-in-eac-or-owa-in-exchange-2013-or-exchange-2016-a24db2f2-4d67-806b-670b-efb8f08605f7